# Enviar Imagens no corpo do e-mail

Tags: html, imagem, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar uma imagem no corpo de um e-mail. Estou montando meu html que vai no e-mail da seguinte forma:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img style='max-height:200px; max-width: 700px; width:auto; height:auto;' src='cid:imagemEmail.jpg'>
  </body>
</html>
```

No outlook a imagem aparece normalmente no e-mail. Já no gmail a imagem está indo como anexo. O que estou fazendo de errado/esquecendo?

Answer (score 1):

Como o Gmail é um serviço online, vc deve especificar um caminho online para a imagem, por exemplo:

```
<img src="http://site.com/imagem.jpg" />
```

Ou seja, a imagem deve estar hospedada em algum lugar na internet.